# Show button after some pixels down using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make an `if check` to show a button but i don't know how to. What i want is that, if scrollbar moves down some pixels then it would show a button. Any help would be nice.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{

var buttonmove = $(window).width() + 'px';
alert(buttonmove );

    if(buttonmove > '1366px')
    {
        $('.Moveup').show();
    }
});
</script>
```

**Below code Not working that why i want to write code manually above:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(window).scroll(function ()
    {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100)
        {
            $('.Moveup').fadeIn();
        }

        else
        {
            $('.Moveup').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

`scrollTop()` never works for me.

**CSS:**

```
.Moveup
{
    width: 53px;
    height: 47px;
    bottom: 10px;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: -52px;
    background: url('../../img/Move Up.png') no-repeat;
}
```

**my scrollbar css:**

```
html, body
{
    scrollbar-face-color: #6e6e6e;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #353535;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #353535;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #353535;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #353535;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #000000;
    scrollbar-track-color: #353535;
}

/*scroll bar for safari & chrome*/

::-webkit-scrollbar 
{
    cursor: move;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment
{
    height: 0px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:increment 
{
    height: 0px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece 
{
    margin-top: 41px;
    background-color: #1D1D1D;
    cursor: move;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical,
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal
{
    border: 1px solid rgb(103, 116, 106);
    background-color: #302E2E;
    -webkit-border-radius: 05px;
}
```

Comment: working for me http://jsfiddle.net/YAcUL/

Comment: i don't know why its not working for me :/

Comment: maybe it's a stupid question but.. did you import jquery? do you get any console error?

Comment: i used alert inside this`$(window).scroll(function ()` but it not geting inside that function

Comment: i am using `-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece`

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the button's `display` property to `none` initially. I can see in the CSS that you haven't.

So, after adding in your CSS this:

```
.Moveup{
    position:absolute;
    top:300px;
    display:none;  /*See this property*/
}
```

### [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/zN44J/) <sup>Scroll down to see effect</sup>

Comment: no my css i edited above. the problem is in picking the scrollbar function which ain't working for me.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "picking the scrollbar function" ?

Comment: What i think the problem is in the scrollbar. I used an alert inside `    $(window).scroll(function ()
    { alert("ok")}` but got no response.

Comment: @user3400389 Do not use alerts please. They block the execution of the rest of the script. Replace it with `console.log` and see the effect. Did it work ? If not, check out the methods told by Benderr

Comment: please explain me what you mean by import?

Comment: Import means to add the following line `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` to your `<head>` element in the beginning. Does this work ?

Comment: nope didn't work. yes i am using `1.9.2 js`. is there to show using code without scrolltop()?

Comment: Launch you `.html` file. And scroll up and down till the place where you expect to see your button. Then press `F12` and go to the `Console` tab. Copy the errors and paste here for us to see. Thanks.